# How can i get results of this sqlite query?

Tags: sqlite

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [test] ([id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,[col1] TEXT  NULL,[col2] TEXT  NULL,[col3] TEXT  NULL,[col4] TEXT  NULL);

INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('A','B','C','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('D','B','D','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('A','B','A','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('B','C','B','B');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('A','B','D','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('C','B','C','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('A','B','D','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('A','B','C','D');
INSERT INTO test (col1,col2,col3,col4)VALUES ('A','B','C','D');
```

---

I want to get results :
I need the last item in the statistics sheet to record the number of consecutive occurrences
    columnname character times

```
    col1       A       3

    col2       B       4

    col3       C       2

    col4       D       5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide,a s something of a [mcve], a tailored toy database. Do so either by using the `.dump`feature or by manually listing a few lines of `create table ...` and `insert ...`. Doing that will get much more attention and helpfulness than posting a picture of text which is incompletely representing your database.

Comment: What is the logic behind A<>col1, B<>Col2, C<>Col3, D<>Col4. Sequential? By what? Do you only have as many different possible values in each column as there are columns? Please explain a lot more about the backgroud and the goal of this. I doubt that without some explanation of logic, answers which happen to create the desired output for the given sample data have much chance of doing what you actually want.

Comment: For example, what would be the desired output if there were also some "F"s? Or is that impossible? If impossible, why? Or what would be desired output for col5, if there are random A,B,C,D inside? Or if that is impossible, then why?

Comment: The data of the column name is a column change, the data of the character is the last record, and the number of data is the number of consecutive occurrences

Comment: I need the number of consecutive occurrences of the last statistic in the table

Comment: Please make a [mcve], a database.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use multi query :

```
SELECT 'col1' as `cols`,col1 as `character`,count(col1) as `nbr` FROM `ets` where id > (SELECT id FROM `ets` where col1 != (SELECT col1 FROM `ets` where id = (select count(col1) from `ets` )) order by id desc limit 1) group by col1

union all
SELECT 'col2' as `cols`,col2 as `character`,count(col2) as `nbr` FROM `ets` where id > (SELECT id FROM `ets` where col2 != (SELECT col2 FROM `ets` where id = (select count(col2) from `ets` )) order by id desc limit 1) group by col2

union all
SELECT 'col3' as `cols`,col3 as `character`,count(col3) as `nbr` FROM `ets` where id > (SELECT id FROM `ets` where col3 != (SELECT col3 FROM `ets` where id = (select count(col3) from `ets` )) order by id desc limit 1) group by col3

union all
SELECT 'col4' as `cols`,col4 as `character`,count(col4) as `nbr` FROM `ets` where id > (SELECT id FROM `ets` where col4 != (SELECT col4 FROM `ets` where id = (select count(col4) from `ets` )) order by id desc limit 1) group by col4
```

Comment: Wouldn't that generate output which also has lines like `col1 B 1` or `col4 B 2` ? Did you test this? Or do you assume that it is what OP acutally wants as part of the output?

Comment: ah i see that the information updated yep i updated my solution Too

Comment: Thank you very much! Your plan can be realized. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: welcome brother , i think there is another solution with  procedure but  i prefer using query